# Automatically disable UIButton with type custom when a UIAlertController covers the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIViewController` containing multiple `UIButton`'s of type `custom`. In cases where my view looses focus like a new view controller gets presented or some other view is added on top of it, how do I gray out(disable) my custom buttons automatically?

Basically I want to gray out the buttons which cannot receive touch and so the user focus is only on the interactive elements on the screen.

I am not using a button type with system because I want to set non-monochrome images for button image.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please show some code or screenshots.

Comment: Unless you are looking for a different type of solution, you should just be able to set your buttons to `button.userInteractionEnabled = false` before you present your alert.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient that the overlapping viewController greys out the whole background?

Comment: Try this button.isEnabled = false

Comment: @zisoft Yes. But for a cases where I create and add a subview on top, which makes the underneath view unresponsive,  I don't want these buttons to give an impression that they are clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `UIAlertController` shows up this changes tint color of the window. That is why non custom buttons are dimmed. These normal and dimmed colors are taken from `tintColor` property. In case of a custom button you can override `tintColorDidChange` method:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override func tintColorDidChange() {
        if tintAdjustmentMode == .dimmed {
            // modify subviews to look disabled
        } else {
            // modify subviews to look enabled
        }   
    }

}
```

But in your case it looks like your image has just one color. And that is why you can make it simpler. Just load button's image with rendering mode `UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate` and change button's `tintColor` be equal to the image's color. Then everything will happen automatically.

Making image be rendered in template mode is pssible with a help of Xcode
[image]

or get it programmatically `originalImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` from original image.

Comment: Thanks for the hint:  __When UIAlertController shows up this changes tint color of the window__.  This helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code.

```
NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *v in subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *) v;
        [button setEnabled:NO];
        [button setAlpha:0.5];
    }
}
```

This code will disable all the UIButtons in current view. You can re-enable the buttons when Alertview is dismissed.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want button as untouchable You can use

`button.enabled = false ;
 button.userInteractionEnabled = false`

before presenting your UIAlertViewController and

`button.enabled = true ;
 button.userInteractionEnabled = true`

after presenting UIAlertViewController

and also if you want to change the color of button  you can use

```
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your gray image"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

or

`[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your gray image"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`

according to your choice

Comment: This I have to do for every custom button in my screen and for every case wherein my view becomes unresponsive and to keep it consistent I have to do in every view controller I'm gonna code. I'm looking more for a generic solution here.